# Redesign select to design I want

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a select box as below:

[image]

However, I want to change the design to this:

[image]

Anyone know a technique to do this in css? Or is it even possible?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not an on topic question as it stands now. Please add effort and code. But first google "style select css" then you will find things like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select  id="my_selection">
</select>
```

CSS:

```
#my_selection {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;       /* remove default arrow */
   background-image: url(../img/drop-down.png);  /* add custom arrow */
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position:right center;
}
```

Use the following code to accomplish what you want.